# Автоматический перенос изменений из ветки master в рабочее дерево?

Tags: git

пытаюсь перенести изменения ветки master из локального репозитория git в удалённый (не bare), и ожидаю что автоматически изменятся файлы в рабочем дереве.
Но получаю ошибку:

> error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master error:
> By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is
> denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent with
> what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match the work
> tree to HEAD. You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch'
> configuration variable to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository
> to allow pushing into its current branch; however, this is not
> recommended unless you arranged to update its work tree to match what
> you pushed in some other way. To squelch this message and still keep
> the default behaviour, set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration
> variable to 'refuse'.
>
> Remote Repository Updates Branch Update : master
> ...
> Result: REJECTED_OTHER_REASON

Как сделать так чтобы при push в удаленный сервер автоматически менялось рабочее дерево?

Comment: Вы хотите чего-то странного. Нормальный способ работы с удаленным репозиторием - использование bare репозиторий в качестве удаленного. Другие варианты ненормальные.

Comment: Никак. Автоматическое обновление рабочего дерева в общем случае невозможно (помним про конфликты слияния), потому такого способа нет и быть не может. Если вы пытаетесь сделать через push колхозный деплой на сервер - советую использовать не push, а хотя бы pull с той стороны. А ещё лучше - что-нибудь созданное именно для деплоя.

Comment: я хочу переносить изменения с локальной машины на рабочую (удалённую) при помощи git, то есть подразумеваем что на рабочей машине код не меняется программистами, а только приходят обновления.

Comment: Не понятно, что вы подразумеваете под "рабочей". Если это например сервер, где крутится сайт или сервис, вам нужны инструменты для развертывания, какой-нибудь ansible, ручное копирование файлов по ssh на худой конец или rsync. Либо если прямо хочется использовать git, то наоборот на рабочей машине нужно делать git pull с какого-то отдельного git репозитория.

Comment: возможно вы правы и я не с той стороны захожу... надо проверить...

Comment: Вот тут ответ на английском https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/how-to-push-to-a-non-bare-git-repository